# How to construct a type trait that can tell if one type's private methods can be called in another type's constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

I am using C++17.  I have code that is like the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Fooer
{
    Fooer (T & fooable)
    {
        fooable . foo ();
    }
};

template <typename T>
Fooer (T & fooable) -> Fooer <T>;

struct Fooable
{
private:

    void
    foo ();

    friend struct Fooer <Fooable>;
};

struct NotFooable
{
};
```

I want to implement a type trait that can tell if a type is 'Fooable'.

I can't check to see if there's a method `foo ()` on the type, because it is a private method.  This also doesn't tell me if `Fooer`'s constructor can call the method.

```
// Checking for the foo method doesn't work.

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasFoo;

template <typename T, typename>
struct HasFoo : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct HasFoo
<
    T,
    std::enable_if_t
    <
        std::is_convertible_v <decltype (std::declval <T> () . foo ()), void>
    >
>
:   std::true_type
{
};

// Both of these assertions fail.
static_assert (HasFoo <Fooable>::value);
static_assert (HasFoo <NotFooable>::value);
```

I also can't check to see if `Fooer <T>` is constructible via `std::is_constructible`, because `std::is_constructible` doesn't check to see if the constructor *definition* is well-formed, only the expression `Fooer <T> fooer (std::declval <T> ())`.

```
// Checking constructibility doesn't work either.

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct CanMakeFooer;

template <typename T, typename>
struct CanMakeFooer : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct CanMakeFooer
<
    T,
    std::enable_if_t <std::is_constructible_v <Fooer <T>, T &>>
>
:   std::true_type
{
};

// Neither of these assertions fail.
static_assert (CanMakeFooer <Fooable>::value);
static_assert (CanMakeFooer <NotFooable>::value);
```

If I actually try to call the constructors, I get the error that I expect, though it does not get me closer to implementing a type trait.

```
void
createFooer ()
{
    Fooable fooable;
    NotFooable not_fooable;

    // This works fine.
    { Fooer fooer (fooable); }

    // This correctly generates the compiler error: no member named 'foo' in
    // 'NotFooable'
    { Fooer fooer (not_fooable); } 
}
```

I want to avoid declaring the type trait as a friend of the Fooable types, and I want to avoid making 'foo' public.

If I could somehow make a type trait check the *definition* of a function or constructor for well-formedness, I could implement this type trait easily enough, but I don't know how to do that, and I can't find any examples of such a thing on the internet.

Is it possible to do what I want?  How do I do this?

Comment: Can you change `Fooer`?

Comment: @aschepler: Change how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble here is that the constructor of `Fooer` is not "SFINAE-friendly". It has a requirement that `Fooer` can call `fooable.foo()`, but as far as C++ is concerned, the declaration `Fooer(T &);` doesn't have any such constraint.

We can change the constructor declaration into a constructor template so that template argument deduction fails for it when the template argument of the class template is not "fooable":

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct Fooer
{
    template <typename U = T, typename Enable =
                std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<U&>().foo())>>
    Fooer (T & fooable)
    {
        fooable . foo ();
    }
};
```

[This will become easier and more legible with C++20 constraints:

```
// C++20 code
template <typename T>
struct Fooer
{
     Fooer (T & fooable) requires requires { fooable.foo(); }
     {
         fooable . foo ();
     }
};
```

]

With that change, your `CanMakeFooer` should work. Though it could be defined more simply with just the primary template and no specializations:

```
template <typename T>
struct CanMakeFooer :
    public std::bool_constant<std::is_constructible_v<Fooer<T>, T&>>
{};
```

[Demo on coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c449abdbc552a8e8)

Comment: Bruh___________

Comment: @Kerndog73 Yup, didn't see your answer appear before I finished and posted mine. At least pretty much agree! Have an upvote.

Comment: Right back at you! I think it's funny that we both independently wrote almost exactly the same solution to the problem

Comment: I accepted this version because of the bonus C++20 answer and cleaner code.  This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

You need to make the call to `foo()` part of the declaration of the `Fooer` constructor and make the constructor SFINAE friendly. You can do this with a constructor template and a default template argument for requirements. This means that `HasFoo` only needs to check if a `Fooer` can be constructed with `T` and doesn't have to worry about the `foo()` function.

```
template <typename T>
struct Fooer {
  template <typename U, typename = std::void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<U &>().foo()),
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, U>>
  >>
  explicit Fooer(U &fooable) {
    fooable.foo();
  }
};

template <typename U>
Fooer(U &) -> Fooer<U>;

template <typename T>
struct HasFoo : std::bool_constant<
  std::is_constructible_v<Fooer<T>, T &>
> {};

struct Fooable {
private:
  void foo() {}

  friend struct Fooer<Fooable>;
};

struct NotFooable {};

static_assert(HasFoo<Fooable>::value);
static_assert(!HasFoo<NotFooable>::value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar approach to your HasFoo but using functions instead of a struct and it works as expected.

```
Fooer (T& fooable)
{
    if constexpr (has_foo<T>(0)) {
        cout << "Yes foo" << endl;
        fooable.foo();
    }
    else {
        cout << "No foo" << endl;
    }
}

template<class Y>
static constexpr auto has_foo(Y*) -> decltype(std::declval<Y>().foo(), bool()) {
    return true;
}

template<class Y>
static constexpr bool has_foo(...) {
    return false;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/5GGY89YVLsfqeZ2A

Comment: This is nice. It does however not give a solution to the question, since OP wants to avoid making the type-trait a friend of `Fooable`. You've indirectly done that by putting the type-traits inside `Fooer`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm just a little bit confused about how these functions are indirect friends of Fooable/NotFooable by begin inside Fooer.

Comment: @super: While it's true that I would prefer a solution that doesn't put additional code inside of `Fooer`, I really meant that I didn't want to have to have two separate friend declarations in any class that was Fooable (one for Fooer and one for IsFooable).  This answer avoids that situation.  If a better answer does not come along, this could become the accepted answer.